# jquery slider in dropdown menu item causing too many events

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I am using a jQuery slider in a dropdown menu item. When I click on the menu item, a dropdown opens with a slider. User is expected to drag one of the slider handles. From that point onwards, any mouse movement on that page causes a slider event and a callback. This continues until I click someplace else on the page, effectively rolling back the menu dowpdown.

Is this behavior normal? How can I have the slider change events stop once the user has released the slider handle? I have a page that reloads from a database whenever the user changes the slider. This is causing excessive load on the database.

I am using jQuery UI with bootstrap. You can see example at http://jsfiddle.net/Sh5A5/2/

Here is the JS:

```
islide = 0;
$("#XYZ").text("DDDDDxD");
$("#XYZ").append("<b class=caret></b>");
$("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    values: [75, 300],
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        alert("hello #" + ++islide);
        $("#XYZ").html("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) + " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) + " <b class='caret'></b>");


    }
});
```

and html:

```
<div class="nav dropdown"> <a id="XYZ" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary" href="#"></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">
                <p>Range: 0 to Inf</p>
                   <div id="slider-range"></div>
                </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried the same without bootstrap. It looks ugly but behaves just the same. Is there a better alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What causing this behavior is this line:

```
alert("hello #" + ++islide);
```

When alert() is called inside the slide event handler the mouse is never released.
So you have to remove the call to alert() : 
http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/eKjCD/